# Why won't my QuillJS Delta insert a space?

Tags: javascript, quill

I have:

```
    const delta = quill.formatText(documentData?.prediction?.range?.index, documentData?.prediction?.range?.length, { accepted: 'accepted' })
    delta.insert('\t')
    quill.updateContents(delta)
```

which creates a `delta` that looks like:

```
ops: [
  {retain: 1617},
  {retain: 63, attributes: {…}},
  {insert: "    "}
]
```

But when my editor doesn't add that space at the end. If I change it to some text (like `hello`), then it inserts `hello`.

But not with a space. Why not?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by _"But when my editor doesn't add that space at the end."_ You just demonstrated that it seems to insert a tab character (`\t`). Are you trying to insert a tab or a space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not very clear - not sure what is the entered data and what is the expected output, but if that's space you want to add, why not use:

```
var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
  theme: 'snow'
});

var ops = [{
    insert: 'This is a test'
  },
];
quill.updateContents(ops)
quill.insertText(0, ' ')
```